# Eclipse menus disabled on OS X 10.9 Beta 6

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-kepler

today I opened my eclipse as usual but I wasn't able to do anything. All menus except the preferences are grayed out, disabled.

I'm on a Mac Mavericks Beta 6 & Eclipse Kepler

Do u have any hints for me? Restart of Eclipse or the complete mac didn't solve the problem

[image: Eclipse Menu]

Comment: I would move my workspace to some other place, start eclipse, create new temporary workspace and look if you can create files in there.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working. I tried to start a new workspace, but without success

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you by any chance install the Mavericks beta 6? This is a known issue, Apple messed up Java. The work around is to install the full JDK http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572. Solved the problem for me.

Comment: Perfekt answer. And yes I am on Mavericks... Don't know why I put Mountain Lion in my question...

Answer (score 2):

Change eclipse startup jvm (Oracle jdk )  will fix this problem, i use oracle jdk 1.7.0_25 and all menu are ok now.

Add this line into Eclipse.ini
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Installing this also solved the problem for me.
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572.